# C# Entity Framework and Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

In the query build below, is there any reason `Where` clause `B` is seperate from `Where` clause `A`?

```
truckList = (from truck in _dbcontext.Truck.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId) //(A)
    join comp in _dbcontext.TruckComponent
    on truck.Equipment.ProtId equals comp.ComponentId
    where truck.EquipmentId > 0 && truck.FieldId > 0 //B
    select NewTruckVmFromDbTruck(truck, comp)).AsEnumerable();
```

Can they just be joined into A or into B? For example as:

```
truckList = (from truck in _dbcontext.Truck.Where(
                x => x.ClientId == clientId && 
                truck.EquipmentId > 0 && 
                truck.FieldId > 0)
                ...rest of query...
             )
```

Comment: When you ran a SQL Trace, did both LINQ queries generate the same database query?

Comment: Where clause B doesn't depend on anything on `comp`, so there's no need to be separate from `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be preferable to not mix fluent and lambda query syntax anyway, how about:

```
truckList = (from truck in _dbcontext.Truck
             where truck.EquipmentId > 0 && truck.FieldId > 0 && truck.ClientId == clientId
             join comp in _dbcontext.TruckComponent on truck.Equipment.ProtId equals comp.ComponentId
             select NewTruckVmFromDbTruck(truck, comp)).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because 'truck' and 'comp' are from different table

```
truckList = (from truck in _dbcontext.Truck.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId) //(A)
join comp in _dbcontext.TruckComponent
on truck.Equipment.ProtId equals comp.ComponentId
where truck.EquipmentId > 0 && truck.FieldId > 0 //B
select NewTruckVmFromDbTruck(truck, comp)).AsEnumerable();
```

truck is from table called "Truck", while
comp is from table called "TruckComponent"

Both have different identities, if you just select the '**Truck**' table, you wont get the '**TruckComponent**' table data.

```
select NewTruckVmFromDbTruck(truck)).AsEnumerable();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `B` is actually not "from TruckComponent". So you are wrong on that one. `B` is independent and applies to both tables. To reference `TruckComponent` you use `comp` as it is defined in the join statement

Comment: Owh, if that so, either way can be used then. I miss the word 'clause'.

Comment: from truck in _dbcontext.Truck.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId && x.EquipmentId > 0 && x.FieldId > 0

Comment: Can you edit you answer to show this instead. The A and B being from different tables part will mislead someone or get you negatives on this answer

Comment: ah i see, kinda tricky question, maybe next time i should be more careful when answering, because you point out the mistakes ive made rather than hoping to find the answer of your problem. Sorry for making silly mistake, wont happened again

Comment: No need to apologise. Im Am trying to find an answer :)... Just not a wrong answer...

Comment: You've made it worse actually lol. My question was on if I can just join the two where statements into one, instead of those two that someone else originally wrote... See the code in my answer. Ive already written the code, just need clarification on whether that is different the top one.

Comment: Ah i see, yes its the same as the top one, except yours cleaner than the above

Comment: it is not different from the top one. even the resulting sql query should be the same (depending on the smartness of your EF provider). The difference in approach is joining on query results (effectively temporary tables) or joining the tables and then filtering the resulting temporary table. However, any query optimizer will move the filtering to the bottom so the joins become cheaper.